# CGAL read_OFF discards face depending on vertex order

Tags: c++, cgal, file-format

When reading an [off-file](http://www.geomview.org/docs/html/OFF.html) with cgal it appears that the vertex order of a face decides whether or not it is read in by [read_OFF](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/group__PkgSurfaceMeshIOFuncOFF.html#ga84a04be1919414fbbaeb84edaf4fb111). But the [off-file](http://www.geomview.org/docs/html/OFF.html) definition does not say anything about the vertex order of a face.

I am reading in self generated [off-files](http://www.geomview.org/docs/html/OFF.html) using the [read_OFF](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/group__PkgSurfaceMeshIOFuncOFF.html#ga84a04be1919414fbbaeb84edaf4fb111) method of cgal:

```
using Kernel = CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel;
using Point_3 = typename Kernel::Point_3;
...
CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3> test_mash;
CGAL::IO::read_OFF(file_name, test_mash);
std::cout << "Number of vertices: " << test_mash.vertices().size() 
      << ", Number of faces: " << test_mash.faces().size() << std::endl;
```

two_faces_read.off:

```
OFF
4 2 0
1 1 1 
2 -2 2
3 3 -3
-4 4 4
3  0 1 2
3  0 3 1
```

one_face_read.off:

```
OFF
4 2 0
1 1 1 
2 -2 2
3 3 -3
-4 4 4
3  0 1 2
3  0 1 3
```

Reading two_faces_read.off works as expected, printing:
`Number of vertices: 4, Number of faces: 2`.
But when i read one_face_read.off i get `Number of vertices: 4, Number of faces: 1`. The only difference between these two files is the last line, the vertex order of the second face is different. After trying all possible combinations it seems that with 031, 103, 310 2 faces are read in, while with 013, 130, 301 only 1 face is read in.
The [off-file](http://www.geomview.org/docs/html/OFF.html) specification referenced by cgal does not mention any rules concerning the vertex order of a face.

Why does this happen and how can i ensure that all faces are read in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`one_face_read.off` does not define a valid surface mesh has the orientation of the two faces are not compatible. You can use the [following function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Stream_support/group__PkgStreamSupportIoFuncsOFF.html#ga6e3b4ee8b72982b74c56f89586745c8d) to read points and faces and call [`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::is_polygon_soup_a_polygon_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga8b9d12d817b5cc76f5a42d74eac75bf3) to check if the input is a valid surface mesh. The function [`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::orient_polygon_soup()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#ga3075a0ae461cf65426620548e24ec2ed) can be used to fix orientations.  [`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga0dec58e8a0112791f72ebbe77bac074b) can be used to create the mesh.